# Save singleChoiceItems AlertDialog option using SharedPreference

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-alertdialog

I've implemented a `singleChoiceItems` `AlertDialog` which opens from a navigation menu in my android app. I'm using it to change the app theme (Light, Dark, System default).
[image]

Now I'm trying to save the current state of the `AlertDialog` in `sharedPrefernces` along with the theme that the user selects. For e.g, if I've selected a dark theme previously, I want the `AlertDialog` to show the same while applying the theme to the app.

Here's the code I've been using.

```
String selectedTheme = "Light";
public  static final String SHARED_PREFS = "sharedPrefs";

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);       
selectedTheme = sharedPreferences.getString("str", "Light");


public void openDialog() {
        String[] themes = {"Light", "Dark", "System default"};
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Choose Theme");
        builder.setSingleChoiceItems(themes, 2, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                selectedTheme = themes[which];
            }
        });
        builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("SHARED_PREFS", MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putString("str", selectedTheme);
                editor.apply();
                if (selectedTheme.equals("Light")) {
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
                }
                else if (selectedTheme.equals("Dark")) {
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
                }
                else {
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM);
                }
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        builder.show();

    }
```

With the above code, the sharedpreferences is not storing the current state. What changes do I need to do in order to make it work?

Comment: `if (selectedTheme.equals("Light"))  editor.putString("str", "Dark");` ??

Comment: `int checkedItem = 2; .setSingleChoiceItems(choices, checkedItem, .......` You are setting it to 0: the first one.

Comment: One line would do: `editor.putString("str", selectedTheme);`

Comment: @blackapps, I tried with your suggestions. It didn't work

Comment: Please edit your code so we can see what you changed and how you determine the value of `checkedItem`. And why didn't react on my first comment?

Comment: I've updated the code block.

Comment: ????? You are not using `checkdItem`. You still have a `0`in `builder.setSingleChoiceItems(themes, 0, ......`.

Comment: It's only going to set the default chekedItem to the `system default`. I want it to represent the current theme.

Comment: Yes, as it makes no sense to put a hard coded `2` there. You should first determine the value for `checkedItem` using the value of `selectedTheme` which you obtained from shared preferences.

Comment: And there my friend lies the problem. I am not sure how to retrieve those values from sharedpreference or even how to save them. Because I've never used it before.

Comment: You retrieve  `selectedTheme` from shared preferences already. You now only have to calculate the value for selectedItem. Say you retrieved `"Dark"` then you should be able to give selectedItem a value of `1`. You should also know already if you saved `selectedTheme` in the right way as you are already retrieving it. So easy to check. Start with the shared preferences code to be ok.

Comment: Can you share with me some links or tutorials where I can get a grasp of it?

Comment: Tutorial? I already told you what to do. After: `selectedTheme = sharedPreferences.getString("str", "Light");` You put code to calculate the value for checkedItem: `int checkedItem = 0; if (selectedTheme.equals("Dark") selectedItem=1; and so on...`  Sigh... Why did you still not tell if the shared preferences code works for you?

Comment: No @blackapps, the shared preference is not working

Comment: Then you should have posted just your shared preferences problem to begin with of course. Its pretty basic saving a string to shared preferences and later retrieving it. You better write another post. And when that is solved come back to this one.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by sharing the string related to the theme in `sharedPreference`.
I also implemented the `AlertDialog` issue where I wanted to check the items which was previously chosen inside the app.

Following is the code I used:

```
String selectedTheme = "Light";
int checkedItem = 0;

public static final String SHARED_PREFS = "sharedPrefs";
public static final String TEXT = "text";
public static final String RADIO = "selected";
```

Then I called `loadData()` and `updateViews()` from `onCreate()`.

```
public void openDialog() {
        String[] themes = {"Light", "Dark", "System default"};
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Choose Theme");

        if (selectedTheme.equals("Light")) {
            checkedItem = 0;
        } else if (selectedTheme.equals("Dark")) {
            checkedItem = 1;
        } else {
            checkedItem = 2;
        }
        builder.setSingleChoiceItems(themes, checkedItem, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                selectedTheme = themes[which];
            }
        });
        builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if (selectedTheme.equals("Light")) {
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
                }
                else if (selectedTheme.equals("Dark")) {
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
                }
                else {
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM);
                }
                saveData();
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        builder.show();

   }
```

```
public void saveData() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(TEXT, selectedTheme);
        editor.putInt("selected", checkedItem);
        editor.apply();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

```
    public void loadData() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
        selectedTheme = sharedPreferences.getString(TEXT, "System default");
        checkedItem = sharedPreferences.getInt("selected", 0);
    }
```

```
    public void updateViews() {
        if (selectedTheme.equals("Light")) {
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
            checkedItem = 0;
        }
        else if (selectedTheme.equals("Dark")) {
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
            checkedItem = 1;
        }
        else {
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM);
            checkedItem = 2;
        }
    }
```

I followed the tutorial from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fJEFZ6EOM9o) link.